# Can't connect Mongodb to Node.js, MEAN-stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm a Mac user and I'm very new to MEAN-stack. I'm trying to connect a Mongoose with my Node.js but it always show this error

```
events.js:141
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^ 
Error: failed to connect to [undefined:27017]
at null.<anonymous> (/Users/toeysk/Desktop/testwebrtc.git/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:556:25)
at emitThree (events.js:97:13)
at emit (events.js:175:7)
at null.<anonymous> (/Users/toeysk/Desktop/testwebrtc.git/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:156:15)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at emit (events.js:172:7)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/toeysk/Desktop/testwebrtc.git/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:534:10)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at connectErrorNT (net.js:996:8)
at doNTCallback2 (node.js:452:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:366:17)
```

I can use both Mongoose and Mongodb normally in my terminal.

Here is my **server.js**

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var mongoose = require('./config/mongoose'); //connect DB
var express = require('./config/express');

var db = mongoose();
var app = express();
app.listen(3000);

module.exports = function(){
    require('../app/routes/index.routes')(app);
    require('../app/routes/user.routes')(app);
};

module.exports = app;
```

And it calls **mongoose.js**

```
var config = require('./config');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

console.log('Mongoose.js');
console.log(config);

module.exports = function(){

    mongoose.set('debug', config.debug);

    var db = mongoose.connect(config.monoUri);

    console.log('Call User Model');
    require('../app/models/user.model');

    return db;
};
```

Then calls **config.js** and **development.js**

```
/////config.js/////

module.exports = require('./env/' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.js');

/////development.js/////

module.exports = {
    debug: true,
    mongoUri: 'mongodb://localhost/webrtc',
    sessionSecret: 'dev_secret_key'
};
```

Please help. I have been trying to debug this about 2 days and I got nothing new. Anything miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pointing you towards the issue:

```
Error: failed to connect to [undefined:27017]
```

So there's something wrong with the location of the database, it looks like the hostname is undefined.

Here's your connection code:

```
var db = mongoose.connect(config.monoUri);
```

And here your configuration:

```
mongoUri: 'mongodb://localhost/webrtc'
```

Can you spot the typo in your connection code? It says `monoUri`, not `mongoUri`.

Answer (score 0):

can you do

```
npm install mongoose
```

and also post the output from

```
ps -ef | grep mongod
```

All on the the machine you are running node from. That would go a long way towards the rest of an answer.

Also follow the simple sample code- https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#introduction, substitute the database name and a collection name and run that on node

```
node sample.js
```